# React Storybook add Svg sprite

Tags: svg, storybook

How to inject SVG sprite in storybook from node_modules?

Currently I am trying to 'import @package-name/src/svg-sprite.svg;', but I am not sure how to adjust 'webpackFinal' in storybook for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I just copy pasted the whole Svg sprite into preview-body.html and it does the job. https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/add-custom-body/